# Scala + Spring boot @Profile annotation

Tags: spring-boot, scala

I'm trying to use profiles in my Scala application which is using spring boot framework.
I only added this annotation to my class

```
@Profile("config.local")
class LocalConfig with Config
```

However the compiler says it expects an array of String, but trying to make it work with Array, Seq, etc it is saying it expect an String there.

This is the error sbt shows:

> Error:(16, 10) type mismatch;  found   : String("config.local")
> required: Array[String] @Profile("config.local")

How can I use spring boot @Profile with Scala classes

Thanks

Comment: Spring Boot does not support Scala. There was an attempt few years ago but it was abandoned. If I were you, I’d not try to fit a square peg in a round hole. Use a framework that natively supports Scala, like Play or Akka.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Profile(Array("config.local"))
```

will work for you, but it may cause errors in the IDE although it compiles successfully.